# How can you insert more than one data tag on a /summon spider command?

Tags: minecraft-commands

So, I tried 
/summon spider 100 20 100 {Health:16.0f}{CustomName:Webby}
then evreything that I could put in the middle with commas and full stops but it won't work, it'll let me use only one data tag but I am making a map that requires several of them for each mob. Obviously I am using Command Blocks in 1.12.2.

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to combine NBT tags in two different commands?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/353511/how-to-combine-nbt-tags-in-two-different-commands)

Answer (score 0):

Tags are separated by commas. In general, you can look up example commands for things like this.

```
/summon spider 100 20 100 {Health:16.0f,CustomName:Webby}
```